# Can I install dual operating systems?

Tags: dual-boot

I wish to evaluate Linux by installing a dual operating system kinda thing. Is that possible?  I'm also interested in cost should I decide to avail myself of this operating system.

Comment: Yes, you can install Ubuntu along side an existing  OS, be it Windows, Mac, or another Linux flavor. As Ubuntu is free, the only 'cost' required is the time you invest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best/most correct way to prepare the HDD for a dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785817/what-is-the-best-most-correct-way-to-prepare-the-hdd-for-a-dual-boot) and [What does it mean when Canonical says that Ubuntu is and always will be Absolutely Free?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9885/what-does-it-mean-when-canonical-says-that-ubuntu-is-and-always-will-be-absolute)

Answer (score 3):

You don't even have to install Linux to test it, as many Linux OSes (such as Ubuntu) allow you to boot straight from the installation media and create a 'live' environment for you to test the OS in.

Also, you can create bootable USBs that have persistence, so that all the changes you make are saved. An example of such a tool that can do this is [Pen Drive Linux](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).